# Consistent mysqldumps across tables: --lock-tables vs --single-transaction

Tags: innodb, mysql, myisam

I have the task to do consistent mysqldumps across tables, so that one database is always consistent with itself (all tables inside).

Now I read that there are two options `--single-transaction` for InnoDB and `--lock-tables` for all others.

My two Question are:

1. Can I simply check if all tables of one database use InnoDB and if so apply `--single-transaction` to that database.
2. If any table inside one database is not using the InnoDB engine can I simply apply `--lock-tables`?

Would the above two cases guarantee me to always have consistent database backups across tables?

**Update:**

By `consistent dumps` I mean, that once the backup process is started, it will dump the current state of one database and no other operation (which might take place at the same time) can interfere with the current state.

Comment: Define "consistent". If you're not using transactions but single shot SQL statements in your application, there's nothing preventing a backup from being taken between any two queries in the middle of a web request (a.k.a. what you could call inconsistent data)

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson
Does it make more sense now (see updated explanation).
I just dont want any inserts that might happen during that time, to polute my backup

Comment: Does your InnoDB _application_ use BEGIN...COMMIT in order to prevent the inconsistency?  That is, everyone needs to play a part in "consistency".